# Why conditional ranking in Excel doesn't work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my dataset

```
apps_category   app        usage_freq   
Tech_Enthusiast mdns          3807967   
Gamers          apexlegends      1556   
Socialities     chubao       11284180   
Gamers          toonblast       92078   
Socialities     xl_kaskus      138451
```

What I did
`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8431,A2,$C$2:$C$8431,"<"+C2)+1`

The Output is

```
apps_category   app        usage_freq   Rank
Tech_Enthusiast mdns          3807967   1
Gamers          apexlegends      1556   1
Socialities     chubao       11284180   1
Gamers          toonblast       92078   1
Socialities     xl_kaskus      138451   1
```

There's at least 2 Gamers and Two Socialities there, why everyone rank there

Comment: You don't show what you want for an result given the data you post, but **this is wrong:  `"<" + C2`**  Should be **`"<" & C2`**

Comment: OK, now I know my mistake, thanks